# $n^{q}\equiv1~(\text{mod $p$})$ is possible solve this?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have the following situation:

Let $p, q$ be a prime numbers were $p>q$ and $n\in\{0,1, \ldots, p-1\}$. In this conditions is possible solve (in function of $n$) this equation, $n^{q}\equiv1~(\text{mod $p$})$ ?

Comment: Solve for $p$ or $p$ and $q$ and $n$?

Comment: Without being told what the unknown is, I can refer you to computation of discrete logarithms as generally the kind of problem this is.

Comment: Soluble for $n$

Comment: The nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ form a multiplicative group of order $p-1$, in fact the cyclic group of that order.  So unless $q$ happens to divide $p-1$, there will not be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $q$ is not a divisor of $p-1$, then $n\equiv 1\pmod p$ in the only solution.

If $q\mid p-1$, then there are $q$ solutions, and you can find them by brute force by computing $n=1^d,2^d, \dots, (p-1)^d$ where $qd=p-1$.